# Github hook event on delete branch cause Jenkins Job failure

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, hook

In Jenkins, I have a pipeline configured to run when a change is made on any Github branch starting with "release".
In order to do that I use a Github hook trigger, and a branch specifier matching the expression "origin/release/*".

In our git workflow, those branches are not meant to live eternally, so they are frequently removed.

What I was expecting is the pipeline to be triggered on each commit of every release branch.
However the pipeline is also triggered when a branch is deleted.

**How can I ignore the delete branch event in my pipeline ?**
I already tried not to send an event from Github when a branch is deleted, but it seems that there is no option for that. The "push" event option is sending an event when a branch is deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: > In Jenkins, I have a pipeline configured to run when a change is made on any Github branch starting with "release" - Which event did you actually setup on the webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue.
Here is how I was beginning the pipeline :

```
node('staging') {
        GIT_PROJECT_NAME = "myrepo"
        stage("clone repository") {
                git credentialsId: "${GIT_PROJECT_NAME}",
                    url: "git@github.com:${GIT_PROJECT_NAME}.git"

                scmVars = checkout scm
                branch = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
                sh ('git checkout ${branch}')
        }
```

The idea behind it was to checkout the branch from which the pipeline was triggered.
However this caused the pipeline to be triggered no matter the branch.

Here is how I solved it :

```
node('staging') {
    GIT_PROJECT_NAME = "myrepo"
    stage("clone repository") {
            scmVars = checkout scm
            branch_tmp = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
            branch = branch_tmp.replace("origin/","")
            git branch: "${branch}",
                credentialsId: "${GIT_PROJECT_NAME}",
                url: "git@github.com:${GIT_PROJECT_NAME}.git"
    }
```

With this, I don't need to "manually" checkout the correct branch.
This solution works, the pipeline is now only triggered when a push is made on branches matching my branch specifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a big deal.
Just leave it fail. Seems no hurt.